# Centos | Yiiframework | Permission Denied

Tags: yii, centos

I am facing permission denied error while trying to deploy an Yii based application on Apache Httpd server, following are logs of same.

> require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/tarun/scripts/yii-1.1.13/framework/yii.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/hellouttarakhand.com/index.php on line 12 [Sat Apr 06
>   14:49:03 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning: 
>   require_once(/home/tarun/scripts/yii-1.1.13/framework/yii.php): failed
>   to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/hellouttarakhand.com/index.php on line 12

Due to above error, application page always appears blank as script is not able to execute.

I have given chmod 777 to yii root folder as well executed following command

> chcon -Rv --type=httpd_user_content_rw_t
>   /home/tarun/scripts/yii-1.1.13/

but still no luck with this error.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `chown -R webserveruser /home/tarun/scripts/yii-1.1.13/`

Comment: And dont forget that the assets/ and protected/runtime folder has to be writeable, too.

Comment: @Tim
if you succesfully "chmod -R 777", it doesn't matter what "chown" you make